# Como hacer con Tkinter que una ventana Toplevel devuelva una valor a la ventana principal y este, sea escrito en un Entry o Label de la principal?

Tags: tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Intento hacer que una ventana principal, reciba un valor tecleado en un Entry de otra ventana (elegí una Toplevel pero podría ser de cualquier tipo) y este valor recibido se incorpore en un Label de la ventana principal. La ventana principal (Ventana1 en el ejemplo) y la secundaria (Ventana2) son clases y están en módulos independientes (Modulo1.py tendrá la clase correspondiente a la Ventana1 y Modulo2.py tendrá la clase correspondiente a la Ventana2.

El problema es que cuando abro una instancia de la clase Ventana2 que es la Toplevel en la función asociada al click del botón de la Ventana1 para abrir la Ventana2, la ejecución del código de esa función que hay después de abrir la instancia no se ejecuta con .destroy de la Ventana2, sino que se ejecuta al final, cuando cierro la ventana principal. He intentado poner otro mainloop() en la Ventana2 y añadir un 'Return' después de ese mainloop, pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

El código de Modulo1.py es:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

import tkinter as tk
import Modulo2

class Ventana1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Ventana 1")
        self.parent.geometry("260x200")
        self.parent.state('normal')
        self.parent.resizable(1, 1)

        frm_principal = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        frm_principal.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frm_principal.config(bg='lightgray', bd=3, relief='ridge')

        self.w_etiqueta = tk.StringVar()
        self.w_etiqueta.set('')
        etiqueta = tk.Label(frm_principal, textvariable=self.w_etiqueta, fg='Black', width=30, justify='right')
        etiqueta.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

        img_bot_ventana2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='Alta.png', master=self)
        bot_ventana2 = tk.Button(frm_principal, command=self.click_bot_ventana2, width=150, height=40, image=img_bot_ventana2,
                                text='Ventana 2', compound="left", bg='lightgray')
        bot_ventana2.image = img_bot_ventana2  # esto permite que se muestre la foto en botón cuando la clase es creada en otra ventana
        bot_ventana2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)


    def iniciar_ventana1(self):

        self.mainloop()


    def click_bot_ventana2(self):

        inst = Modulo2.LlamarVentana2(root)
        codigo = inst.llamando_ventana2()

        messagebox.showinfo(message="Modulo 1 en click_bot_ventana2 {}".format(codigo), title="Mensaje")
        self.w_etiqueta.set(codigo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Ventana1(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

y el código del Modulo2.py es:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

import tkinter as tk

class Ventana2(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title('Ventana2')
        self.geometry("260x200")
        self.state('normal')
        self.resizable(1, 1)
        self.grab_set()
        self.texto_tecleado = ""

        self.frm_principal = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frm_principal.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.frm_principal.config(bg='lightgray', bd=3, relief='ridge')

        self.texto = tk.Entry(self.frm_principal, fg='Black', width=30, justify='left')
        self.texto.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

        img_bot_ventana1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='Alta.png', master=self)
        self.bot_ventana1 = tk.Button(self.frm_principal, command=self.click_bot_ventana1, width=150, height= 40, image=img_bot_ventana1,
                               text='Ventana 1', compound="left", bg='lightgray')
        self.bot_ventana1.image = img_bot_ventana1
        self.bot_ventana1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.texto.focus_set()
        self.parent.withdraw()

    def lanzar_ventana2(self):
        self.mainloop()
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Modulo 2 en lanzar_ventana2 {}".format(self.texto_tecleado), title="Mensaje")
        return self.texto_tecleado

    def click_bot_ventana1(self):
        self.texto_tecleado = self.texto.get()
        self.parent.deiconify()
        self.destroy()

class LlamarVentana2:

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent=parent
        self.codigo_ventana2 = 0

    def llamando_ventana2(self):
        self.formulario = Ventana2(self.parent)
        self.codigo_ventana2 = self.formulario.lanzar_ventana2()
        return self.codigo_ventana2
```

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Me acabo de dar cuenta que la solución es sustituir el self.mainloop() de la función lanzar_ventana2 de la clase Ventana2 (Modulo2.py) para poner un self.wait_window().
Ya me funciona correctamente.